# What is the point of groupBox in WFA in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

Is groupBox in WFA in C# **usefull for something else** than "just saying these components which are inside this groupBox belongs to one group"? 
Can I for example somehow get any information(get it from the groupBox not from the components inside) what happens inside or similar useful things?

Answer (score 1):

Here is Microsoft's design guidelines for using Group Boxes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511459.aspx

They say, "aside from possibly providing an access key for a group of controls, it provides no functionality". The access key being used most commonly in the Radio Button case.

Comment: Note that certain *third-party* group boxes expand on this idea, e.g. DevExpress's group box has a "value" that is the "value" of the selected item, but the default Windows one is pretty thin.

Answer (score 0):

I love using groupBoxes for the "only one radio button may be selected at a time" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is useful as a container that you want to hide or show its content for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

The typical use for a group box is to contain a logical group of RadioButton controls.If you have two group boxes, each of which contain several option buttons (also known as radio buttons), each group of buttons is mutually exclusive, setting one option value per group.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)